# PDF Sharp not generating correct pdf of html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using PdfSharp to generate pdf document. my content is html. it generates pdf well but content inside pdf is not correct. content have many images and html tags. so pdf pages not getting correct design my code for pdf is :-

```
string fullpath = "", fileName = "";

try
{
    _ILocationService.Book(model);

    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();


    string noSpace = Regex.Replace(model.BookName, " ", "");
    string removeSpecialCharacter = RemoveDigits(noSpace).Replace(":", "");
    fileName = Regex.Replace(removeSpecialCharacter, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "") + ".pdf";
    fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/OtherDocuments"), fileName);

    string html = "";

    html += model.BookPage;
    html += string.Join("<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'></p>", model.CollectionBookList.Select(x => x.BookPage).ToArray());
    //byte[] pdfBytes = (new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(html).;
    ////System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullpath, pdf.BinaryData);
    //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullpath, pdfBytes);
    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
    pdf.Save(fullpath);
```

and my html in "html" variable is

```
<p><img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Yv54zzwTL._SX326_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img alt="Image result for images global green" src="http://www.chooseprint.org/images/TwoSides/GoingPaperlessNotGreener.png" style="height:372px; width:254px" /></p>
<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'></p><p><img alt="" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/40142/new-york-skyline-manhattan-hudson-40142.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;h=650&amp;w=940" style="height:100%; width:100%" /></p>
<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'></p><p><img alt="" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374710/pexels-photo-374710.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260%201x,%20https://images.pexels.com/photos/374710/pexels-photo-374710.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260%202x" style="float:left; height:132px; width:200px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

<h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>

<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'></p><p><img alt="" src="https://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/building-7.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%" /></p>

<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'></p><p><img alt="" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/358382/pexels-photo-358382.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;h=650&amp;w=940" style="height:100%; width:100%" /></p>
<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'></p><p><img alt="" src="http://localhost:8032//UploadFile/BookImagesLibrary/1/thumb-1920-583852.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%" /></p>
```

please help me to sort out this issue
check the image of pdf generated book
[Pds generated file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMVWx.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "pdf pages not getting correct design"? Are you talking about image not loading?

Comment: Image loading correctly. but design is incorrect @Rahatur

Comment: "Incorrect design" is a very vague statement. What is the problem with design? Can you add some screenshot to the question?

Comment: Actually I am creating a book. for this in my code I using ckeditor to make different-2 pages or can say templates which have content with images or only images or only content so I want them get as a pdf book with A4 size. so when I do it my some content is coming half goes to next page or image cuts. please check image i attached also@Rahatur